# How to call an web services daily 8 am when app is in background state

Tags: ios, objective-c, background

i need to call a web service daily 8AM, when app is in background state

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}
```

and the response shows in Local notifications,

local notification i done, but that time web service call is not happening

```
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

    NSDictionary * credentialsData = @{@"username": [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"username"],
                                       @"password": [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"password"]};
    NSDictionary *dictReminders = @{@"method" : @"fetchNotifications",
                                  @"credentials" : credentialsData,
                                  };
    NSDictionary * mainDicReminders = @{@"params":dictReminders};
    [[HSEGenWebAPIMapper apiMapper]fetchingReminders:mainDicReminders success:^(NSDictionary *userInfo) {
        //Background Thread
        NSLog(@"arrayReminders count is ------ %lu",(unsigned long)[[HSEAppData appData].arrayReminders count]);
        [self saveNotificationInDB];

    }failure:^(NSDictionary *errorInfo) {

    }];
});

}
```

Comment: That's why we have push notifications,. BTW there is background fetch but that's not exactly what you need. As far as I know there isn't any straight forward way to do it and unfortunately I don't know the other hacky way to do it.

Comment: You can't execute code at a specific time when your app is suspended. You can use the background fetch function to periodically fetch data, but iOS will decide when to perform the fetch. You can use a silent push but you would need a server and to have the server track the device's Timezone to know when 8 o'clock is for a particular device.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore  my purpose is to call one api daily 8 am and show the response in a local notification. i done with local notification, only web service call is not happens

Comment: @Chinjoo can u please  explain briefly , am stuck on this task